# Factory reset turned off realme phone that bootloops without using volume button

Tags: factory-reset, boot-loop, unbricking

I have realme 6 RMX2001 that bootloops and needs a factory reset.
The volume buttons of the device are broken.
The only working button is the power button.

Is it possible to factory reset the device or boot into recovery mode with a PC ?